# D3 use data from arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, visualization

I am using D3 to visualize some data. The chart works find when reading TSV file. However, I would like to use the x and y axis to represent data from two separate arrays. This is what I've got:

```
var Arr1 = "some data"

var Arr2 = "some data"

 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return Arr1; }));

 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Arr2; })]);
```

I know that is not the appropriate way to replace it. Anyone able to advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass the new arrays to the appropriate functions:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(Arr1));
y.domain([0, d3.max(Arr2)]);
```

Comment: Hello Sir, Appreciate the prompt response. Did what you suggested but still unable to display. Anyway, on the x axis is a list of strings, while y is integer.

Comment: Then it should be `x.domain(Arr1)`.

Comment: Hi, yes, i already got it showing on the X axis and y axis. Guess now it is the linkage part as the bar is not showing.